# Cannot delete Azure Notification Hubs registration

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I keep getting 404s when trying to delete a registration from the Azure Notification Hubs REST service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/dn223268(v=azure.100)

```
DELETE https://----.servicebus.windows.net/----/registrations/2093271643335093528-496263142074869927-2?api-version=2015-01
```

I have the Authorization and Content-Type headers, and the registration ID was returned by the feedback service, so it must be valid.

For `If-Match`, I'm using `*`. I'm not sure if it's required, and I don't store them in my backend. I don't see the purpose of it anyway, since the registration ID is already provided on the querystring.

Comment: Could you please try to use get method to read the registration?

Comment: @JimXu Good call. No, the GET registrations/<regId> call also returns 404. What is the feedback returning then??

Comment: If so, it may that someone has deleted it or the id is wrong. Could you please tell me how you create registration.

Comment: @JimXu, The IDs just came from the feedback service, so no one would have had a chance to delete them. And if they were deleted, they should not be returned as invalid - they should just not exist. What's strange is that these tokens never get purged by PNS. The list of invalid tokens just keeps growing over time.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Notification Hubs (ANH) employs logic to automatically clean up invalid registrations containing invalid device tokens after sends. Hence, what likely happened is

1. You target the registration for a send request.
2. ANH receives a bad token / invalid device response from the Push Notification Service provider when it tries to notify the device.
3. ANH removes the registration containing this invalid device from the backend.

This would explain why you get back a registration id from feedback that will no longer exist when you try to get/remove it.

Comment: So I don't have to delete them myself? If so, why do I keep getting the same tokens over and over from the feedback list? There are over 4k of them, dating back years!

Comment: that's interesting. If the registrations contain invalid tokens, they shouldn't be targeted multiple times unless the registration is somehow being recreated. Another alternative to avoid manual deletion is setting an expiry on the registration (expired registrations will automatically be removed by a background cleanup job).